# How to make chatbot application in Android using Openfire and XMPP

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

I want to make on Android application in which i can create one user which acts like chatbot. On chat window when user type any thing and send then instead of other user reply to that question my custom function on open-fire reply static message. I am new to openfire. Not sure how to achieve this. So far i have installed XMPP server and openfire server on my system and i am able to do one to one chat using Pigdin and Spark.

To achieve what i need should i make android application in which i write some custom function or do i have to make custom plugin for openfire. I was doing some RND on this got below some reference :-

https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1130

But reading this i am still confuse what to do and how to do. Can any one please help me out here, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility can be:

User A is using your android application, User B is logged-in on Openfire using any server side XMPP library (for example: smack).

Now whenever User A sends message to User B, it will be routed to User B and there you can respond to it from code.

Or

Instead of implementing User B part, you can write an Openfire plugin which will be checking every message packet, if recipient is User B, you can respond to that message from there.

Regarding your posted link of Botz, first of all it's too old. Secondly it seems like it does almost same thing which i wrote above when writing a plugin.

Comment: Second one seems good to me. I have created on java project on eclipse. Add openfire code into that project as show in this below video.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMaBplFbuQ&t=5s . But now i am not sure how to make this plugin upload on open fire.So if you can guide me .